# Why is there inconsistent behaviour in different tenants when deleting folders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, delete, subfolders

I have a document library in a SharePoint Online site.  When I try to delete a folder with sub-folders and content items in the folder I get the error message as follows:-

> you have to delete all the items in this folder before you can delete the folder

None of the folders selected with sub-folders or items will be deleted.

In a different tenant with similar set up I can delete folders that contain sub-folders and items within that folder.

[image: Deleting folder error]

Why is there inconsistent behaviour for this delete folder action?

Comment: What's different between the two libraries? Is there a lot of content (more than 5000 items) in the folders where you can't delete?

Comment: There's only couple of folders in each library for testing this out.  The folder contains 2 sub folders and 5 items. I noticed the issue in one tenant so I then tested it in a library on the other tenant to see if it happens there.  Folders with sub folders and content can be deleted on the other.  Settings are the same.

Comment: Do you have any checked-out documents?

Comment: @Tally no. no checked out documents.  Check-in/Check-out is not turned on on either library.  Note that the references I am seeing to this issue are all related to OneDrive and ODFB.  I'm seeing it in SharePoint Online.  For example, this post: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother-mso_o365b/you-have-to-delete-all-the-items-in-this-folder/79263a86-ecdb-4528-a936-570b8a5fe140?auth=1

Comment: Do you have any Shares or broken inheritance on the files or folders? And are you a Site Collection or tenant admin?

Comment: @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP am a Site Collection Admin and tenant admin on both tenants.  There's no shares or broken inheritance.  I have manually deleted the sub-content and then deleted the top level folder.  Then copied in a new folder and get the same message with the newly created test folder.